# Accessing Java annotations from a Taglet

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc, taglet

I'm working on a project where we have some custom Taglet classes that are used to modify the Javadocs (such as linking to source code in SVN, adding citations) and so on.One of the things we'd like to do is to be able to get the annotations that are used in the source and manipulate the information from them.

It seems that the Taglet interface does not provide an easy way to access annotations in the Java source code. Does anybody know if this is at all possible?

I'm using JDK 1.5

Comment: I have the same problem! I'm disappointed that there aren't any detailed solutions offered.

Comment: Also running into this. Any improvements for this in 1.7 or 1.8? (I'm not seeing any but hoping I'm just missing something)

Answer (score 3):

If your taglet is called from the standard doclet, you can access its internal state:

```
import com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard;

ClassDoc currentcd = Standard.htmlDoclet.configuration.currentcd;
```

I have written a Taglet that uses this technique, but it sure ain't pretty ;-)

Comment: Sounds good. It would be good it this could be exposed in the JavaDoc API too, instead of via internal interfaces.